# How to test IPv6 and IPv4 web server?

Tags: ipv6

I have setup a web server (Nginx) and assigned an IPv4 address and an IPv6 address to it. In the DNS I have set an A record and an AAAA record. Now, I need to check whether its working. I need to check whether an IPv6 only client can view my site. Whether an IPv4 only client can view the site (I think IPv4 only clients can view because im IPv4 ).

How can I do this? I only have IPv4!

Comment: If you only have IPv6 then how are you posting on this site?

Comment: This is pretty basic - you need IPv4 connectivity to check IPv4 functionality. If you don't have it, get a friend with IPv4 connectivity to test the IPv4 address. Or use a site like http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com

Comment: @voretaq7 Really sorry for the mistake.. Not IPv6... I have only IPv4 connectivity!

Comment: @EApubs . . . so replace "4" with "6" in my comment (and strike the part about downforeveryoneorjustme.com as I don't think they support v6 yet) -- this is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online validator at [ipv6-test.com](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php) can test your Web site for IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity.

Comment: Can I test it locally?