# How can I troubleshoot an Apache subdomain timing out?

Tags: apache-2.4, timeout

I have several subdomains on my server, all giving me timeouts when contacting from any http client (either in HTTP on 80 or HTTPS on 443, depending on the subdomain).

For example : http://test.yosko.net

When contacted directly from the same server, the HTTP request works and is logged by Apache:

```
$ wget http://test.yosko.net/
...
2020-08-19 12:34:20 (603 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [6/6]
```

But when done from any other client, I get a timeout, and can't find anything in Apache's error.log or access.log.

At first I thought about a problem on my certbot configuration for my HTTPS subdomains, but since it is the same for the HTTP subdomains, I suppose it is a broader problem. As there is no proxy nor reverse-proxy on the server, I can't see where it comes from.

It occurred suddenly, without any change from my part a few days ago, and since then, things worked a few hours here and there between long periods of failings.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Additional information: I'm using Apache 2.4 on an Ubuntu Server 20.04.

### Edit 1: IPv6 problem

As suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/421462/164944), I tested my link above on [ipv6-test.com](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php) and it indeed gave a timeout. I suppose that my ISP tries to contact my website in IPv6 (where it fails), whereas other people still try in IPv4 (where it works).

But now I see I could have tried it myself. From my clients:

```sh
$ wget -4 http://test.yosko.net/
...
2020-08-20 09:25:53 (151 KB/s) - «index.html» enregistré [6/6]

$ wget -6 http://test.yosko.net/
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
```

### Edit 2: current config

My current `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` is the default one, listening from all IPs:

```
Listen 80
```

And it does work with IPv6 (see "`tcp6`" mention):

```sh
$ sudo netstat -lnptu | grep "apache2\W*$"
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      89445/apache2       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      89445/apache2
```

And my vhosts too:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

I've also tried this, but the problem remains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 [::]:80>
```

Comment: The URL provided above is responding OK.

Comment: well... that's interesting. It is not responding for me. So the problem is either on my clients or the provider... I didn't even think of that. And here I was, trying to troubleshoot this on my server for hours...

Comment: Yes, check DNS resolver etc.

Comment: That's what I did, and ```nslookup``` was OK from my clients. But thanks to a friend, I found where it fails: the server responds correctly in IPv4, but fails in IPv6! Now I just need to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site test.yosko.net resolves to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses:

```
triss:~> dig test.yosko.net +short
yosko.net.
91.121.170.211
triss:~> dig test.yosko.net +short aaaa
yosko.net.
2001:41d0:1:ebd3::1
```

but it fails to even respond to ping on IPv6:

```
triss:~> ping -6 -c 20 test.yosko.net
PING test.yosko.net(2001:41d0:1:ebd3::1 (2001:41d0:1:ebd3::1)) 56 data bytes

--- test.yosko.net ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 493ms
```

Are you sure you correctly configured IPv6 on that host? If yes - is firewall in place and blocking it? If you are using a tunnel - have you enabled appropriate protocol in IPv4 firewall and set correct MTU on tunnel interface?

In the mean time I suggest removing AAAA record for this hostname and only re-enable it once IPv6 is proven to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added information on my IPv6 config, but it may not be enough. I'll investigate it once I get back home in a few days, because from here it is quite complicated. In the meantime, I'll just disabled my AAAA record and for now, it works.